# I can't edit my homepage - the page editor is just blank

Tags: pages, widgets, links

I've been tasked with taking over the website for my company - going well for the most part, but I've hit a wall with the homepage.

I'm trying to update the Latest Issue widget 
[image]

Problem is, when I go to the page editor it comes up blank:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone has some suggestions? I'm definitely on the right page because it says 'Front Page' next to it on the page list.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You sure it's not the widgets page you should be editing? Widgets aren't changed by editing the page they appear on